# wordpress _e function

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

it shows"-- `Debug: Undefined variable: wordscut on line 168 of /wp-content/theme`"

```
function cutstr($string, $length) {
         $string =strip_tags($string);
        preg_match_all("/[x01-x7f]|[xc2-xdf][x80-xbf]|xe0[xa0-xbf][x80-xbf]|
[xe1-xef][x80-xbf][x80-xbf]|xf0[x90-xbf][x80-xbf][x80-xbf]|[xf1-xf7][x80-xbf][x80-xbf][x80-xbf]/", $string, $info);  
         for($i=0; $i<count($info[0]); $i++) {
                $wordscut.= $info[0][$i];
                $j= ord($info[0][$i]) > 127 ? $j + 2 : $j + 1;
                 if ($j > $length - 3) {
                         return $wordscut." ...";
                 }
         }
         return join('', $info[0]);
}
```

the above is my function. i know in php, it's right if a variable doesn't be declared before it is used.why it shows"`Undefined variable: wordscut, j`.....  thank you.

2,* REQUIRED: `Non-printable characters were found in the '''functions.php'`'' file. You may want to check this file for errors.

what is `Non-printable characters` .how to correct it? thank you.

Comment: for #2 question. It's better to split it as another question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one one classic bug.

When PHP started your script, $wordscut is not defined. When you run

```
$wordscut .= "sometext";
```

The code actually do

```
$wordscut = $wordscut . "sometext";
```

At this point, $wordscut is not available, thus Undefined Variable error occurred.

To fix it, add

```
$wordscut = '';
```

before

```
for($i=0; $i<count($info[0]); $i++) {
```

Comment: but it also shows $j  is not defined,how to expalin it? thank you

Comment: look at your line: `$j= ord($info[0][$i]) > 127 ? $j + 2 : $j + 1;`. At this point, PHP doesn't recognize `$j`. But, at the same line, you call it (`$j + 2` & `$j + 1`). PHP will parse that first and then set the result to `$j`. That's why you get undefined variable. To fix it, add `$j = 0;` before loop `for`

Comment: that error require a more intensive bug-fixing. To start, try this URL: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/non-printable-characters-were-found-twenty-ten